# Session conditions in a symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, layout, controller

When working with symfony2, I'd like to show different layouts (base.html.twig for guests, and layout.html.twig for logged users).

And when a user is connected to his account, he can also (As facebook does) "connect as" a page or a group (always inside his account), and for these two I have to show different layouts as well (pagelayout.html.twig and grouplayout.html.twig).

It seems that the solution is to create a controller (indexAction for example), containing all the conditions over the sessions and database queries.

For example (I changed the code for simplification):

```
public function indexAction(){

     // ...
     if (!$mySession) { //the user is not connected          
         //redirection to home controller that uses base.twig.html          
     } else {  //the user is logged in
          if ($connectAs=='profile') {
                  //redirection to home controller that uses layout.twig.html   
          } else if($connectAs=='page') {
                 //redirection to page controller that uses pagelayout.twig.html  
          } else if($connectAs=='group') {
                 //redirection to group controller that uses grouplayout.twig.html
          }
     }
}
```

I wanted to use these conditions in one redirecting controller, but I think it's not a flexible solution. For I can integrate other types of layouts and controllers, I may need to add more conditions.

Is there a better solution, Than can be more flexible?

**Edit** : Another problem with this solution, is that even if a user is connected as a "Page" , he can still type in the URL of the route to the Group or User controller and get access to them too... unless I added conditions in these controllers too.

**What I need exactly, is creating a controller that acts like a frontController**

Comment: Why don't you just set a `$template` variable and pass it to the render function of the controller?

Comment: Because, It's not only a matter of layouts, it's also a matter of database data, tables of pages and groups are different as well as their queries, that's why I'll need to use different controllers from separated Bundles

Comment: So, I think I need to create something that acts like a frontController, that processes this data and decides which controller to execute.

Comment: But that is what you already have, i don't understand the problem i guess. :/

Comment: The solution above (indexAction) solves the problem (right?), but it doesn't act like a frontController... Because even if I'm connected as a "page" (and indexAction redirects me to pageAction for e.g), I can still type in the URL of the route (/group) , and voila: I got access to groupAction without actually connecting as "group".

You see the difference? If it were a frontController, all the queries will pass by it, and I won't be able to jump to groupAction or pageAction.

Comment: Maybe you could work with multiple firewalls.

Comment: Ok then you need dynamic routing i guess.

Comment: Yes, I will use dynamic routing if I didn't find other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a frontcontroller like logic you need to catch all possible routes with one controller and then forword from there.

```
# all other routed efinitions should go above this,
# so that _frontcontroller acts like a fallback

_frontcontroller:
    path:     /{url}
    defaults: { _controller: YourFrontBundle:Front:index }
    requirements:
        name: ".+" #allow / in the route
```

And your controller should then forward to the controller based on conditions and url

```
public function indexAction($url)
{
    // ...
    } else if ($connectAs=='group') {
        $this->forward('YourGroupBundle:Group:index');
        // or something else based on the url parameter
    }
    // ...
}
```

Also there is the CMF Bundle which has [dynamic routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html) but i didn't digg into that yet.

Comment: Yeah, my friend, thank you so much ... this is exactly what I need , I'm going to forward my controllers . Thanks again. +1